# Retrieving a SQL Server OUTPUT parameter value from a stored procedure

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

I have been following the documentation on the pyodbc page on PyPi and I can't seem to get the code to work.
https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Calling-Stored-Procedures

Using Python 3.8.10

```
conn = pyodbc.connect(connString)
cursor = conn.cursor()
startSQL = '''
    DECLARE @load_id INT;
    EXEC dbo.ETL_StartLoad @JobName = 'test',  @LoadID = @load_id output;
    SELECT @load_id AS Load_ID;
'''
print(startSQL)
cursor.execute(startSQL)
auditList = cursor.fetchall()
print(auditList)
```

When I run the code it fails with the following error:

```
auditList = cursor.fetchall()
pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.
```

If I copy and paste the SQL in SSMS and run it then it works just fine.

Comment: I think you need to start with """\

Comment: See the updated [wiki page](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Calling-Stored-Procedures). TL;DR - You need to put `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the beginning of your anynymous code block.

Comment: @GordThompson this worked. Please answer the question so i can give you credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most common cause of

> pyodbc.ProgrammingError: No results.  Previous SQL was not a query.

when executing a stored procedure is that the procedure itself does not include `SET NOCOUNT ON;`and it performs DML actions (INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE) that return a rowcount. To avoid the error, include `SET NOCOUNT ON;` at the beginning of the anonymous code block, e.g.,

```py
startSQL = '''\
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @load_id INT;
    EXEC dbo.ETL_StartLoad @JobName = 'test',  @LoadID = @load_id output;
    SELECT @load_id AS Load_ID;
'''
```

Comment: The transaction returns the correct value to the command prompt but in the database the transaction is getting rolled back. So the value doesnt exists in the DB anymore when I query it directly. Any Python specific reason for this?

Comment: Are you calling `conn.commit()` to commit the changes?

Comment: Since the code inside the sproc is wrapped in a transaction I didnt think I needed to commit the sproc code again in the python code. Adding the conn.commit() works. Thank you so much!